Why does my intel hd 4000 graphics not support directx 11 feature level 11?
I have intel HD 4000 graphics on my pc, but every time I try t run a game (Driving life and others), it keeps saying:
A D3D11 compatible GPU (feature level 11, shader mode 5.0) is required to run this engine.
According to Tech power up intel HD graphics have direct x 12 (feature level 11, shader mode 5.0). I ran dxdiag command, and my system shows I have DirectX 12, and the feature level is 11_0, 10_1.... isn't it supposed to run a d3d11 gamepic for reference?

The game might be checking for a specific feature that your graphics card does not have. It might be using an 11_1 feature while yours is only 11_0, and instead of being specific it is just saying "11" is needed. Intel HD graphics is pretty awful for modern games.

Thank you for this,  that should be the problem
